# Pre-fill WebView text fields

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to pre-fill text fields in a `UIWebView` and am given to understand that `javascript` is the best way to go about this. Unfortunately I know nothing of `javascript` and have been fumbling about for the last few hours, getting nowhere.

Latest botched attempt:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // username field id = username_5 & pw field id = password_5
    NSString *javascript = @"\
    var user = 'testUser';\
    var pw = 'testPW';\
    document.getElementById('username_5').value = user; \
    document.getElementById('password_5').value = pw; \
    ;";
    // Execute JS
    [_emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

-EDIT-

I also tried tried delaying the call in case the page had not fully loaded and if I call something like:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wv
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(injectJavascript) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void)injectJavascript
{
    [self.emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('password_5').value = 'testPW';"]];
    [self.emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.alert('test');"]];
}
```

the alert appears but the field with ID `password_5` is not filled.

The fields in question are nested within a form. Don't know if that makes any difference?

-EDIT 2-

I'm pretty sure the problem is related to the HTML / nesting on the target website as I just tried this on another site and it worked.

The target site is nested like this:

```
<html>
  <head> … </head>
    <body onload="FinishLoad(1);hideJSWarn();">
      <div id="noJSWarn" class="cssSecurityWarning" style="display: none;"> … </div>
      <table id="table_LoginPage_1" > … </table>
      <table id="table_LoginPage_2" > … </table>
      <blockquote>
        <form id="frmLogin_4" onsubmit="return Login(1)" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="login.cgi" name="frmLogin">
          <input id="tz_offset_5" type="hidden" name="tz_offset"></input>
          <table id="table_LoginPage_3" >
            <tbody>
              <tr> … 
                <td valign="top">
                  <table id="table_LoginPage_6" >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td> … </td>
                        <td> 
                          <input id="username_5" type="text" size="20" name="username"></input>
```

Comment: Im not sure if it will help, but aren't u missing `;` after the `'testPW'`?

Comment: I just tested your code (with the added `;` I suggested in previous comment) and your JS code works fine for me. So maybe check your HTML code if its OK

Comment: Still not working so may well be the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had obtained the element IDs by highlighting them in Firefox and selecting `inspect element`.
Turns out this gives different IDs to those returned with:

```
NSString *body = [self.emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                  @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML"];            
NSLog(@"%@", body);
```

Plugging these IDs (which apparently vary dependent upon what was used to navigate to the page) into:

```
[self.emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('username').value = '%@';", user]];
[self.emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('password').value = '%@';", pw]];
[self.emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('input_LoginPage-ipad_1').click();"]];
```

Solved it.

Thanks for all your help folks.

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644551/auto-fill-forms-in-webview-by-javascript-android . it needs your help.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put the javascript code inside one NSString and then execute with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. This is how the code would look like:

```
 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('email').value = '%@'", email]];
 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('pass').value = '%@'", password]];
```

Comment: Np. Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Still no joy. A colleague managed to prefill the fields via `C#` script but the same `javascript` isn't working from `Objective-C`.

Comment: This for sure work, I copied from one project of mine. The problem must be somewhere else. Check if you are passing the correct 'ID' in the javascript function, check if your webView is correctly, if it's delegate is been set, etc.

Comment: I've edited the OP to show some other testing. AFAICT the delegate is set correctly, the element IDs are correct and HTML is fully loaded before calling the `js`.

Comment: @LucasEduardo please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644551/auto-fill-forms-in-webview-by-javascript-android . it needs your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code This will Work

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
    + " document.getElementById('login').value = '" + emailAdress+ "';"
    + " document.getElementById('login').readOnly='true'"
    + "})();");
```